# Piping to grep and using regex

Tags: regex, bash

Basically what I want to do is parse lines in a file and return usernames. Usernames are always surrounded in < and >, so I want to use regex to match eveything before (and including) the < and everything after (and including) the >, and then invert my match. I understand that grep -vE should be able to do this.

My script looks a little something like this so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
        echo $line | grep -vE '(.*<)|(>.*)'
done < test_log
```

And test_log consists of the following:

```
Mar  1 09:28:08 (IP redacted) dovecot: pop3-login: Login: user=<emcjannet>, method=PLAIN, rip=(IP redacted), lip=(IP redacted)
Mar  1 09:27:53 (IP redacted) dovecot: pop3-login: Login: user=<dprotzak>, method=PLAIN, rip=(IP redacted), lip=(IP redacted)
Mar  1 09:28:28 (IP redacted) dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<gconnie>, method=PLAIN, rip=(IP redacted), lip=(IP redacted), TLS
Mar  1 09:27:25 (IP redacted) dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<gconnie>, method=PLAIN, rip=(IP redacted), lip=(IP redacted), TLS
```

However, when running my script, nothing is returned, despite when I test the regex in something like regexpal with an inverse match it does exactly what I want. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the invert. The -v means "find lines where this pattern does not match". I think a better approach is to simply capture the username. Is that accurate?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

try this grep line:

```
grep -Po "(?<=<)[^>]*"
```

or more secure:

```
grep -Po "(?<=user=<)[^>]*"
```

**EDIT**

short explanation

```
-P perl-regex
-o only matching
you can get above info from man page
(?<=foo)bar look-behind assertion. matches bar, only if bar is following foo.
[^>]* any not > characters.
```

Comment: Well I'll be. That did it, I'm using the bottom one for more security. Thank you. EDIT: I'm still somewhat green when it comes to regex. Could you or someone else explain that one to me?

Answer (score 8):

Actually, I like @Kent's answer too and it is correct, but sometimes it is difficult to remember switches like *"-Po"* for *"grep"* utility. Usually if you don't remember exact flag you may ask grep utility to refresh your memory in a following way:

```
$ grep --help | grep regex
  -E, --extended-regexp     PATTERN is an extended regular expression (ERE)
  -G, --basic-regexp        PATTERN is a basic regular expression (BRE)
  -P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
  -e, --regexp=PATTERN      use PATTERN for matching
  -w, --word-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole words
  -x, --line-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole lines
```

As we can see, there also another possible options, like *"-E"*.

Answer (score 0):

I actually like @Kent's answer better, but if we can assume a recent version of grep and you want to avoid perl based regular expressions you can still extract the username directly:

```
echo $line | grep -o '<[^>]*>' | grep -o '[^<>]*'
```

Comment: Why would one want to avoid Perlish regexes?

Comment: Because of the comment in the manpage: `This is  highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.`

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need an external program if your data is as consistent as you show.

```
while read line; do
    line="${line#*user=<}"  # Remove from left up to <
    line="${line%%>*}"      # Remove to right from >
    echo $line
done < test_log
```